# Unable to understand the difference between some keywords and functions with RandomX

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, mining-technical-details

I am unable to understand what the reference CPU is, the SuperScaler hash program and the VM of RandomX.

How the programs are run on the RXVM.

What is the role of SuperScaler.

Comment: I HAVE READ specs.md but cant get clear picture of whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unable to understand what the reference CPU is, the SuperScaler hash program and the VM of RandomX.

Reference CPU: https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/master/doc/specs.md#62-the-reference-cpu

SuperScaler hash: https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/master/doc/design.md#34-superscalarhash

Superscalar processor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor

RandomX Virtual Machine: https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/master/doc/design.md#2-virtual-machine-architecture and https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/master/doc/specs.md#4-virtual-machine

> How the programs are run on the RXVM.

Allocate & initialize the cache, dataset and VM, then run in a function like:
https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/v1.1.10/src/randomx.cpp#L349-L368
(e.g. `machine->run(...)`)

Comment: can you link the code of superscalar hash function code

Comment: https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/v1.1.10/src/superscalar.cpp